# generate an real url with rails for an e-mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, url, dynamic, hyperlink

We want to send an autogenerated E-Mail with an full path to the profile. How do we this

```
<%=link_to('Link', :controller => 'mycontroller', :action => 'show', :id => @mycontroller.id )%>
```

The link_to command only builds the link in the mail like this

```
mycontroller/show/id
```

we need an link like this structure

```
http://www.server.tld/mycontroller/show/id
```

Can everyone help us please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass :only_path => false

```
<%= link_to('Link', :controller => 'mycontroller', :action => 'show', :id => @mycontroller.id, :only_path => false ) %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works fine. I only had to add `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }` to my development.rb then `only_path => false` worked