# How to show a profile with link_to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, url, dynamic, hyperlink

In the last we generated a useful link for our mail.
[generate an real url with rails for an e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437811/generate-an-real-url-with-rails-for-an-e-mail)
This works fine, very fine. But we want to call the shoe-action :-)

```
<%=link_to('Link', :controller => 'mycontroller', :action => 'show', :id => @mycontroller.id )%>
```

The url looks so

```
http://localhost:3000/mycontroller/show/10
```

we need this structure

```
http://localhost:3000/mycontroller/10
```

The `rake routes` command said this

```
mycontroller GET    /mycontroller/:id(.:format)               mycontroller#show
```

How do we get the needed structure? Do we need to edit our routes, or is there another way to get the right url?

Comment: How your `routes.rb` file looks now? Can you paste it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the route helper

```
  mycontroller_url(@mycontroller.id)
```

instead the {:controller => ..., :action => ...}

your link_to helper should look like this for better example i use the user show action

rake routes return this

```
user GET  /users/:id(.:format) users#show
```

and now I know I can use the user_url(@user) helper

```
<%=link_to('Link', user_url(@user) )%>
```

Comment: This works but there is an other error. The `:only_path => false` will not be taken. the url looks so `mycontroller/:id`thats right but without host.

Comment: An solution not the best is to build an url and not an link `<%=url_for(:action => 'show', :controller => 'wishlists',:only_path => false, :id => @wishlist.id)%>`

Comment: ok you should probably set the host in your mail setup or in mailer

Comment: Thats it we need no links we need urls :-) Thanks to you. good night